# Is there a way to see a track of one single file (out of all other files) on github?

Tags: github

So basically after you commit something on github and change a particular file, and then if someone else goes in and change that particular file , is there a way to just keep track changes made on just  that one file??
Thanks

Comment: So you are looking for a visual/gui for `git blame`?

Comment: i did not know about git blame...but its sounds like its exactly what i'm looking for hahaha

Comment: I don't think github has what you need but you can clone the repo locally and use sourcetree http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/ to visually track what is going on on each commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each file on GitHub has an history link which will give you access to the list of commits including that specific file:

See [my script for instance](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/make_env.sh):

[image: click on History]

If you click on `History`, you can then select any commit which included changes for that file:

[image: commits for a file]

You will then see the changes for that specific file:

[image: changes]

But don't forget the '`Blame`' button:
It will display the file with all the contributions highlighted for you:

[image: blame view]